# ffmpegでエラーが出る: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

以前も同様の質問をしましたが、コマンドを乗せたほうが良いというアドバイスを受け、再投稿です。

ffmpegでmp4を圧縮し、最終的にはVOBに変換したいと考えていますが、以下のようなエラーになります。
元ファイル名は便宜上original.mp4としています。

どこがおかしいのかお分かりになる有識者の方のご教授お待ちしております。

```
C:\Users\USER> ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe
ffmpeg version N-108306-ge7a987d7c9-20220923 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.55_3defb7b)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220923
  libavutil      57. 36.102 / 57. 36.102
  libavcodec     59. 44.101 / 59. 44.101
  libavformat    59. 32.101 / 59. 32.101
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 49.100 /  8. 49.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

```
C:\Users\USER> ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -crf 10 compressed.mp4
ffmpeg version N-108306-ge7a987d7c9-20220923 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.55_3defb7b)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220923
  libavutil      57. 36.102 / 57. 36.102
  libavcodec     59. 44.101 / 59. 44.101
  libavformat    59. 32.101 / 59. 32.101
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 49.100 /  8. 49.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
original.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Comment: 「ご教授」という程ではないのですが、`original.mp4: No such file or directory` と表示されていますので `original.mp4` ファイルがどこか別の場所(ディレクトリ)にあるという事なのでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

"original.mp4: No such file or directory" は指定したファイルが見つからないというエラーです。

手っ取り早くは対象の動画ファイルを ffmpeg.exe と同じフォルダに移動してから実行するか、
もしくは以下の通り「動画ファイルのあるフォルダに移動」してから「FFmpeg をフルパスで呼び出す」方法を試してください。

```
C:\> cd 動画のあるフォルダ

C:\動画のあるフォルダ> C:\Users\USER\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe -i original.mp4 -crf 10 compressed.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

[windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10) ならば `original.mp4` があるフォルダを explorer で表示させた状態で、フォルダパスのバー [PC>ボリューム(D:)>mp4] 部分をクリックして任意のコマンド（EXE名）を入力すると、そのフォルダ（ディレクトリ）を「カレントディレクトリ」にして当該プログラムが起動します。 `cmd` と入力すればコマンドプロンプトが、 `powershell` と入力すればパワーシェルが起動します。

そののちは @cubick さんの手続きで `ffmpeg.exe` を起動してみてください。

本来は システムの詳細設定→環境変数→ユーザー環境変数 で、環境変数 `PATH` に `ffmpeg.exe` を配置しているディレクトリを追加するのが面倒無くて良いのですが・・・